# Computing mean direction of river network in R

Tags: shapefile, r, line, direction

I have a shapefile of a section of river network (polyline) which I have read into R using the `sp` package to have a SpatialLinesDataFrame. I also have access to a terrain raster for the region in which the river section lies. I wish to find the mean direction of the river network (analogous to ArcGIS's Linear Directional Mean) but I want to keep it in R.

I can't see the function I want in the `sp` or `rgdal` or `raster` packages. Is there a package with the appropriate function in it?

PS.
This ([Is there an R alternative for ArcMap's linear directional mean tool?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240382/is-there-an-r-alternative-for-arcmaps-linear-directional-mean-tool)) question shows the brute force method using a table with x_start, x_end, y_start, y_end. Is there anything better than this? If not, how do I extract such a table from a SpatialLinesDataFrame?